# Using a validator callout extender with FCKEditor does not set "left" style

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor, ajaxcontroltoolkit, customvalidator

As it says in the title, I'm doing custom validation with FCK (because the `RequiredFieldValidator` doesn't work with `FCKEditor`).  When validation fails, the callout appears, but it does not show up in the correctposition.

Generated `style` tag: `visibility: visible; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 646px; z-index: 1000;`

Not that `left` is coming as `0px`. (The `top` isn't quite right either, but it's close enough for now)

Here's my markup:

```
<FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor ID="FCKeditorBody" runat="server" Width="600" Height="150" ToolbarSet="Basic"></FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor>
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvBody" ControlToValidate="FCKeditorBody" SetFocusOnError="true" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a body." ClientValidationFunction="ValidateBody" ValidateEmptyText="true" 
    ValidationGroup="ValgrpPost" Display="None" />
<asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="Server" ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender7" BehaviorID="vceBID" TargetControlID="cvBody"
        HighlightCssClass="ValidatorCalloutHighlightCSS" CssClass="RecipeCalloutCSS" PopupPosition="TopLeft" />

<script type="Text/javascript">
    function ValidateBody(source, args) {
        var fckBody = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('<%=FCKeditorBody.ClientID %>');
        args.IsValid = fckBody.GetXHTML(true) != "";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you put an element with position:relative around the FCKeditor and the validator, then it will show at the top left of the FCKeditor.

```
<div style="position:relative">
    <FCKeditorV2:FCKeditor ... />
    <asp:CustomValidator ... />
    <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ... />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ValidateBody(source, args) {
            var fckBody = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('<%=FCKeditorBody.ClientID %>');
            args.IsValid = fckBody.GetXHTML(true) != "";
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

The message will now cover the toolbar and block the buttons untill you press the "x". A backgroundcolor should be added to the message to make it better visible.

If you wanted to show it inside the textarea of the editor, maybe `PopupPosition="BottomRight"` is better for that. Or you could overrule the generated css with an !important rule.

```
 .RecipeCalloutCSS{ left:0!important; top:65px!important; }
```

Comment: After all that, all I needed was an `!important` rule.  Well, I learned something about CSS today!  Thanks!  Enjoy your bounty!